# Understanding Task Dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to grok how tasks depend on one another in SBT.  Using 0.13.7.  'inspect' and 'inspect tree' have been lifesavers, however I still find examples that I can't explain.

For example, I know that 'publishLocal' ends up calling 'copyResources' *somehow*, but if you run 'inspect tree publishLocal', you don't see the copyResources task in the tree.  I can see the 'Copying Resources' output when running with debug logging on and I know that log statement comes from inside the copyResourcesTask function.  Is there some other way this is getting invoked?  Some other way to see these dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Some dependencies are *dynamic*, in the sense that they are computed *while running a task*. This dependencies cannot be shown by `inspect tree` because identifying them would require executing the task. And then again, the dependency could change from one run to the next.

See the [documentation about `taskDyn`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Tasks.html#Dynamic+Computations+with).

I don't know of any way to *show* the actual dependencies, though.